# Triggering powershell scripts when creating/updating/deleting Git branches on TFS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, githooks

I 've some Git repositories on a TFS2017 server. The goal is to implement a method to deploy a web everytime a branch is created on this git repository, update the web when the branch is updated and delete the web when the branch is deleted.

I though using a powershell script for this, and I already have it implemented. The problem now is to execute this script every time a branch is created/updated/deleted.

I tried to use the Server-Side Git Hooks events to do this, but then I realized TFS is not implementing those hooks.

I was thinking in using a CI build setup to solve the creating/updating part of the problem, but then I realized that creating a branch from the server control panel will not trigger the CI's build.

So I'm looking for a solution for the creating/deleting problem.

I readed about Integrated Services in TFS. Looking at the list the only one which I find usefull for this problem is sending a HTTP request to a service (I would made a service for executing my scripts) but then I couldn't find any appropiated trigger on the drop-down menu for creating/deleting branches...

I'm a bit lost here, any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime looking for a workaround I figured out a solution in two steps.

On the one hand I have addressed the problem of creating and updating the website by using a TFS's CI Build that has a task which launches a PowerShell script. This PowerShell script uses Invoke-Command to execute commands in the remote machine who has the IIS server where I plan to publish this websites. You can find more info about this PowerShell remote execution [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/). I used [WebAdminitration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/?view=winserver2012-ps) module for Powershell to manage the IIS Server.

The main problem that I had to implement this approach was to find the right way to trigger this TFS's CI Build. The solution I found was to configure the CI trigger in a very open way (see the picture that follows). I did this because my developer's team can create any number of feature branches, and therefore I can't manually add the CI to every branch. I can use the "exclude branch" to prevent this CI Build to be triggered by my main branches. As you can see you have a lot of flexibility to play around.

[image]

On the other hand I couldn't use any TFS's CI Build to delete the websites when a branch is deleted, because TFS doesn't have any event that can be listened to detect when this is happening. So I had to find another solution.

After giving it a thought I came out with the idea to have a Windows Service to periodically check for the Git branches and compare them with the published webs in the IIS server. I just needed to add this service to the machine that hosts the IIS and give the process enought privileges to modify the folder that contains the IIS configuration files (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config). I also needed to have the right credentials for the TFS in the windows credentials manager.

I used the library [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet) to controll the IIS and the libraries [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/dn245587(v=vs.140)), [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet) and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi to comunicate with the TFS's Git repository.

I'm actually doing some test, but for now this looks like the right approach for my problem. If this doens't work I'll post the next experiment.